# ¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)?

Tags: nodejs, powershell, localhost, server

estoy aprendiendo a gestionar un servidor usando NodeJS y por primera vez estoy usando PowerShell. Cuando quiero parar el servidor le doy CTRL+C y PowerShell me pregunta "¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)?". Alguien sabe a que se refiere esta pregunta de PowerShell?
Gracias

Comment: es una mala traduccion, por 'lotes' significa batch se refiere a si deseas terminar el proceso batch. Lo cual se debe interpretar por, "estas seguro de terminar el proceso?"
tomalo como una advertencia a veces no queremos cerrar el servidor, eso es todo

Comment: Puedes ver el siguiente vídeo: https://youtu.be/qJxYoiFzIC0